# Remove duplicates from merged streams

Tags: typescript, rxjs, distinct

I have two observables:

```
interface Hour {
   id:string;
}

const hours$: Observable<Hour[]> = this.hoursCollection.valueChanges();
const availableHours$: Observable<Hour[]> = this.availableHoursCollection.valueChanges()
```

I'm combining the two observables
I have some duplicate items that have the same id as a value
if the hours.id === availableHours.id then the object in hours should be filtered out

I tried distinct but I don't get the part where you compare values

```
this.events = Observable.combineLatest(hours$, availableHours$, (hours, availableHours) => [...hours, ...availableHours]).distinct()
```

Comment: The code snippets don't make sense. In one place, you refer to `hours.id` and in another you use the array spread syntax with `hours`. Some data would make this clearer. At the moment, anyone answering will have to make some guesses.

Comment: Please check if the types that I added are correct OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumming that your streams emit **arrays**:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';

this.events = combineLatest(hours$, availableHours$, (hours, availableHours) =>{
  return hours.reduce((acc,actual)=>{
    if(!acc.some(hour => hour.id === actual.id)){
       acc = [...acc,actual];
    }
    return acc;
  },[...availableHours]);
});
```

Comment: thanks this works partially, if I remove an item of the availableHours observable, the events dont update, also I dont really understand the code

Comment: If you mutate the list emited by availableHours$ but dont emit the new value , there is no way that the events stream will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using RxJs 4 compatible version.

`distinct()` should work, actually. However, if you're dealing with complex event objects rather than primitives, you should provide a key selector (and maybe a comparer):

> Arguments
>
> `[keySelector]` (`Function`): A function to compute the comparison key for each element.
>
> `[comparer]` (`Function`): Used to compare objects for equality. If not provided, defaults to an equality comparer function.
>
> [Source: RxJs extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md)

**Example**

> ```
> /* With key selector */
> var source = Rx.Observable
>   .of({value: 42}, {value: 24}, {value: 42}, {value: 24})
>   .distinct(function (x) { return x.value; });
> ```

In your case it could be `.distinct(hours => hours.id)` (if `id` is the the key which can be used to compare objects).

---

I have never used `distinct()` myself, but rather `distinctUntilChanged()` which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

distinct() is used to compare a new emitted value against the last emitted value. It won't remove duplicates from the combined array.

So let's say you have a util function that filters out duplicates from an array called removeDuplicates() you could use it like so, in your stream:

```
this.events = Observable
    .combineLatest(hours$, availableHours$, 
        (hours, availableHours) => {
            return [...hours, ...availableHours].removeDuplicates();
    })
    .distinct()
    .subscribe((hours) => {
        doSomethingWithUniqueHours(hours);
    });
```

In this case you would still use distinct() to filter out an emitted value (an array of hours) that is the same as the last that was emitted.

Comment: the distinct() here is noop, as a new array will always be emitted

Comment: As @Igor Soloydenko pointed out in his answer, you just need to pass in a selector and comparer so distinct has a proper way to compare an array objects. It doesn't matter if a "new array" is emitted. Whether it's the same is what counts.